# Trying to calculate Pi

Tags: c, pi

To calculate Pi you can use the equation pi/4=1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+...
Multiply it by 4 and you get Pi
I created a formula to calculate each step of the equation relative to its position 1/(2n-1) and wrote code for it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    double p = 0;
    double pi = 0;
    int j = 1;

    do 
    {
        if (j % 2 == 1)
        {
            p = p + (1 / (2 * j - 1));
        }
        else
        {
            p = p - (1 / (2 * j - 1));
        }
        pi = p * 4;

        printf("%lf\n", pi);

        j++;
    } while (j < 10);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

but it is only putting out `4.0000`
Why? I cant find the mistake I made.

Comment: Change `p = p + (1 / (2 * j - 1));` to `p = p + (1.0 / (2 * j - 1));`

Comment: `(1 / (2 * j - 1))` is an integer division

Comment: `pi/4=1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+...` This formula converges *extremely* slowly. This is the worst method to compute `pi`.

Comment: @liliscent my goal is this slow conversion. Im going to plot this afterwards.

Comment: the first problem I see is that ALL the literals are integer rather than double.  I.E. rather than 1 use 1.0  rather than 2 use 2.0 etc.  As it is, all the calculations are being performed with integers. When performing calculations with integers, the fraction is dropped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the statement `p = p + (1 / (2 * j - 1));` expression `(1 / (2 * j - 1)` yields in integer. To get expected result make either operand as floating type i.e either `1.0` or `(float)(2 * j - 1)`

Replace the statement

```
p = p + (1 / (2 * j - 1));/* 1/(2*j-1) results in integer, you won't get expected result */
```

with

```
p = p + (1. / (2 * j - 1));/* 1. means making floating type */
```

Answer (score 4):

In your expression

```
1 / (2 * j - 1)
```

both operands of `/` are of type `int`, therefore it performs an integer division, which truncates the fraction. If you want to perform a real division, make sure at least one of the operands has a floating point type. You can easily achieve this here by writing

```
1.0 / (2 * j - 1)
```

A numeric constant containing a decimal point (and without a suffix) is of type `double` in C.